# C++ drawing map accordingly to the speed

Tags: c++, sdl

I am trying to create my own version of River ride (2D game) in C++ using SDL library. In the game player flies a plane that is on the bottom of the screen and the goal is to pass the level without taking damage from enemies or hitting the earth. What I have now are couple of bitmaps representing land and water. I draw the map from the notepad where i store 1s and 0s which represnet land and water accordingly.

So i have a notepad stating the layout of the level. I put all those values into map array. I found out on the internet that I could move the map by the velocity of the plane. Unfortunately i do not know how to achieve such effect.

```
SDL_Rect blockarray[200];
for(int y=0;y<16;y++){
    for(int x=0;x<8;x++){
        int surfacetype = getsurface(x,y);
        int color=0;
        switch (surfacetype)
        {
        case 0:
            color=blue;
            break;
        case 1:
            color=green;
            break;
        default:
            color=blue;
            break;
        }
        blockarray[i].x=80+60*x;
        blockarray[i].y=60*y;
        blockarray[i].h=60;
        blockarray[i].w=60;
        i++
    }
}
```

What i want to find out is: how do I assemble those small blocks I have into one surface or how do I treat them as one when I try to move the map downards as the plane is going up.

Notepad:

```
1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0
1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0
1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0
1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0
1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0
1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0
1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0
1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0
1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0
1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0
1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0
1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0
1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0
1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0
1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0
1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using

```
int SDL_BlitSurface(SDL_Surface*    src,
                    const SDL_Rect* srcrect,
                    SDL_Surface*    dst,
                    SDL_Rect*       dstrect)
```

I suggest you create three `SDL_Surface*` before your loop, one for water, one for land and one for the entire map.

You are already creating the `SDL_Rect` for the induvidual tiles in your loop so all you are missing is an `SDL_Rect` for the entire map ( `w = 8 * 60, h = 200 * 60`. )

Then you blit the corresponding tile to the map something like this `SDL_BlitSurface( tileLand, blockarray[i], mapSurface, mapRect);`

And now `mapSurface` is your entire map. If you're not going to use the tile surfaces any more, you should free them with `SDL_FreeSurface( srf );`